# If $\forall x \in G, \exists k \in \mathbb Z^+ \backepsilon xa=a^kx $, then $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, normal-subgroups, solution-verification

In Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, Chapter 14 Exercise E3 asks the reader to prove the following statement:

> If $a$ is any element of $G$, $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ **iff** $a$ has the following property: $\forall x \in G, \exists k \in \mathbb Z^+ \backepsilon xa=a^kx $

For this biconditional, I have no issue demonstrating the implication that:

*if $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup, then $\forall x \in G, \exists k \in \mathbb Z^+ \backepsilon xa=a^kx $*.

However, it is the **other** implication that I am struggling with...specifically:

*if $\forall x \in G, \exists k \in \mathbb Z^+ \backepsilon xa=a^kx $, then $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup*.

Here is the issue that I am running into:

Given the antecedent, I can premultiply by $x^{-1}$ to arrive at:

$a=x^{-1}a^kx$ , which is equal to $a = (x^{-1})a^k(x^{-1})^{-1}$

At first glance this seems just fine...but then I realized that due to the existential quantifier, I am pretty sure that I have **no way of knowing if all elements of $\langle a \rangle$ will make it into $a^k$**. At most, I can say that at least one element of $\langle a \rangle$ has all of its conjugates in $\langle a \rangle$...for example, if $k$ is the same integer for all values of $x$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $\backepsilon$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh, it's a notation I've seen for "such that"...is there a better one?

Comment: I have never seen it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22385/latex-symbols-for-therefore-and-suchthat...the first answer (in case you were wondering)

Comment: Now I've seen it! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: How do you prove the first implication in the case when $\langle a\rangle$ is infinite? When $\langle a\rangle$ is normal in $G$, $\langle a\rangle$ is closed under conjugates so $xax^{-1}\in\langle a\rangle$ for all $x\in G$. Thus, $xax^{-1}=a^k$ for some integer $k$, so $xa=a^kx$. But how can you guarantee $k$ will be positive when $\langle a\rangle$ is infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $ xa^nx^{-1}=a^{nk}$ can you prove this?

Comment: I had thought about this, but my concern was that $\langle a \rangle$ does not necessarily equal $\langle a^n \rangle$...and therefore I would be talking about different groups.

Comment: Ohhhhh, but I guess the idea would be that all $\langle a^n \rangle$'s are necessarily subsets of $\langle a \rangle$...right?

Comment: $a$ is not just any element, it is the generator of the group

Comment: That idea is that every element can be written as $a^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in here, i cant write as you maths symbols with my phone so i solved it on paper sorry my english is bad :|

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZhkR.jpg)